# XSLT: display value of several childnodes with same name

Tags: node.js, xml, xslt, nodes

I am new to XSLTs and have an XML similar to this one:

```
<unit name="test1">
    <unit_meta>
        <label>abcdef</label>
    </unit_meta>
    <item name="test1">
        <item_meta/>
        <valuedate>20180101</valuedat>
    </item>
</unit>
<unit name="test2">
    <unit_meta>
        <label>qwert</label>
    </unit_meta>
    <item name="test2">
        <item_meta>
            <label>blabla</label>
        </item_meta>
        <valuedate>20182020</valuedate>
    </item>
</unit>
<unit name="test3">
    <unit_meta>
        <label>wasd</label>
    </unit_meta>
    <item name="test3">
        <item_meta>
            <label>asdf</label>
        </item_meta>
        <valuedate>20180303</valuedate>
    </item>
</unit>
```

Basically I have childnodes of a node, and inside there are 2 more childnodes.  Then it goes back out to basic node, and it is the same thing again.  The node itself has the same name over and over, except the name-'Tag' (if that is what its called) is different.

I would like to know how to display all of the labels and valuedates of all those nodes.  I can print out the first node but do not know how to get to the next unit node with tag 'test2'.

In my original file there are around 100 of those same repeating unit nodes and I would like to print their labels and values.  What would be the smartest approach?

I do not have much written XSLT code to show. Basically I just scope down to the main node, which has all the unit-Nodes.

Then I have a template, that scopes into unit node and prints out unit_meta/label, and then prints out item/valuedate..

It works for the first node unit "test1", and then it leaves the rest empty.  Any help please?

Comment: Formatting, ponctuation, paragraphs.

Comment: This is a very basic XSLT coding exercise, it's not at all clear why you are having trouble with it, and it's very hard to respond other than by writing a beginning XSLT tutorial. But there are plenty of those around already. I suggest you do some more reading about XSLT, then go back to do some coding, then come back here when you get stuck, showing us the code you have written so we can see what stage you are at in the learning curve.